# IntelliJ IDEA not indexing Java files in Scala/sbt project?

Tags: intellij-idea

I have a project in Scala/sbt that calls some Java files, which are included in the same project, and somehow IntelliJ IDEA is not indexing the Java files (cannot use jump to defition, etc.).

The project builds and runs fine, though. I'm using 2018.1.6 Community Edition. Anyone has a similar problem?

Comment: Are the files under a directory that is marked as sources?

Comment: Yes. They're in a subfoler, along side with a scala src folder. The parent folder is marked as source. However, somehow the Java source seems not appearing in the Project Explorer.